# Handling exception thrown from overrided function

Tags: .net, exception, overriding, webclient

I call a method that may throw an exception from within an overrided function. If `MyBase.GetWebResponse()` throws an exception, how could I catch it from main code? Debugger stops in `GetWebResponse`, not in the main `Try`.

I use the overrided function in order to get redirected ResponseUri. Without using `GetWebResponse`, I can catch exceptions.

Main code:

```
Try
    RetryAction(Sub()
                    Using cawc As New CookieAwareWebClient)
                        strContent = cawc.DownloadString(m_url)
                        m_url = cawc.ResponseUri.ToString
                    End Using
                End Sub, 10, 1000)
Catch ex As WebException
    StreamNotAvailable(ex)
End Try
```

Function:

```
Public Sub RetryAction(action As Action, numRetries As Integer, retryTimeout As Integer)
        If action Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("action")
        End If
        ' slightly safer...
        Do
            Try
                action()
                Exit Sub
            Catch
                If numRetries <= 0 Then
                    Throw
                Else
                    ' improved to avoid silent failure
                    Thread.Sleep(retryTimeout)
                End If
            End Try
        Loop While Interlocked.Decrement(numRetries) > -1
    End Sub
```

Class:

```
Public Class CookieAwareWebClient
    Inherits WebClient

    ...

    Private m_ResponseUri As Uri
    Public ReadOnly Property ResponseUri() As Uri
        Get
            Return m_ResponseUri
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function GetWebResponse(request As WebRequest) As WebResponse
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = MyBase.GetWebResponse(request)
            m_ResponseUri = response.ResponseUri
            Return response
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
Try
    RetryAction(Sub()
                    Try
                        Using cawc As New CookieAwareWebClient)
                            strContent = cawc.DownloadString(m_url)
                            m_url = cawc.ResponseUri.ToString
                        End Using
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Throw
                    End Try
                End Sub, 10, 1000)
Catch ex As WebException
    StreamNotAvailable(ex)
End Try
```